# How to hyperlink call comand with commandparameter in xaml devexpress?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, hyperlink, command

I have hyperlink like bellow, and i try call command by click to hyperlink!

```
<Hyperlink Command="{Binding ResidentChangeCommand}"
               CommandParameter="ChangeMaritalStatus">
                    <TextBlock Text="history" />
                </Hyperlink>
    private ICommand _residentChangeCommand;
    public ICommand ResidentChangeCommand {
        get {
            return _residentChangeCommand ?? (_residentChangeCommand = new          DelegateCommand<object>(OnResidentChange));
        }
    }

    public void OnResidentChange(object obj) {
        WindowResidentCard window = new WindowResidentCard(obj.ToString());
        window.ShowDialog();
    }
```

but nothing happens!!! What the problem??? Any ideas! thank's!!!

Comment: Name="adminControl"  your control and                                                              <Hyperlink Command="{Binding DataContext.ResidentChangeCommand,ElementName=adminControl}"  CommandParameter="ChangeMaritalStatus">

Comment: just set name to your control

Comment: Looks good, if you're sorted, then you should close the question.